# How to make Postfix require authentication for internal mail?

Tags: postfix

I'm receiving mail from phishers using fake local addresses
I understand that mails originated in mynetworks doesn't require authentication (for cron jobs and the like), but shouldn't someone in another country require authentication even if they are sending withing my domain?

Example: currently i'm allowed to send from someone@mydomain.tld to someoneelse@mydomain.tld without authenticating, even if i'm connecting from a different country and not from mynetworks.

in main.cf, mynetworks only has localhost set

Is there something i can do about that?

**Further explanation**
Take the site [smtper](https://www.smtper.net/) for example.
It's not hosted on my servers (probably not in my country either) so i would expect if i place the host and port for my server, not put proper credentials and request a mail to be sent from and to emails i'm hosting it should fail. But it doesn't. It passes through fine.

**Request Info**

As requested, here's my main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name powered by Easy Hosting Control Panel (ehcp) on Ubuntu, www.ehcp.net
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes

# TLS Incoming
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/path/to/my/certificate.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/path/to/my/certificate.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile=/path/to/my/certificate.ca-bundle
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers=high
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, CAMELLIA, eNULL, aNULL
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, CAMELLIA,  eNULL, aNULL
smtpd_tls_loglevel=1
smtpd_tls_received_header=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout=3600s
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_starttls_timeout = 300s
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache

# TLS Outgoing
smtp_tls_cert_file=/path/to/my/certificate.crt
smtp_tls_key_file=/path/to/my/certificate.key
smtp_tls_CAfile=/path/to/my/certificate.ca-bundle
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers=high
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, CAMELLIA, eNULL, aNULL
smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, CAMELLIA, SRP, 3DES, eNULL
smtp_tls_loglevel=1
smtp_tls_received_header=yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_timeout=3600s
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_starttls_timeout = 300s
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# General Configuration
myhostname = mydomain.tld
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
debug_peer_list = 
debug_peer_level = 1
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_protocols = ipv4
inet_interfaces = all
smtpd_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
smtpd_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtpd_extra_recipient_limit = 10
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20

# Virtual domains, mailboxes, etc
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_mailbox_extended = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_maildir_limit_message = "The user you are trying to reach is over quota."
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_message_limit = 0
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
default_process_limit = 3
sender_canonical_maps = 
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps $transport_maps

# SASL Authentication
#smtpd_sasl_type = courier
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

# Restrictions
#smtpd_delay_reject = yes
#smtpd_helo_required = yes
#smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, permit
#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
#smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unlisted_sender, permit
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client b1.spamcop.net, check_policy_service unix:postgrey/socket, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/client_checks

# milters & filters (Amavis & DKIM)
content_filter = smtp-amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
milter_protocol = 2
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

Comment: You only need to implement SPF (what you should have anyway) to disallow mails from unauthorized sources.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Internal mail ignores spf and Dkim

Comment: Regarding your edit: Yes, that should fail. If you would provide your main.cf we would be able to tell you what could be improved.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider added main.cf as requested

Answer (score 1):

> currently I'm allowed to send from someone@mydomain.tld to someoneelse@mydomain.tld without authenticating, even if i'm connecting from a different country and not from mynetworks.

What happens there is expected and mostly by design. The nuance in is that **those messages don't get sent, they are received** by your mail server.

Receiving mail for any local domain name will never require authentication, because how would the other sending mail servers authenticate? You can't supply usernames and passwords to Hotmail, Gmail, example.com and everybody else that might send you email so that they will authenticate when sending messages to your domain...

To make an exception for the special case where the sender claims to be a mailbox from within your own domain requires you to  implement SPF. SPF is used to create and enforce a policy to **restrict which servers may send email for your domain**. (You should do that regardless of this issue.)

That will allow your mailserver to reject incoming messages that claim to be from your own email domain, but which get sent from ip-addresses that are not white-listed beforehand. If the sender succesfully authenticates they will by-pass the SPF check and the message will be accepted for delivery.

Comment: not according to the headers - emails from local addresses to local addresses ignore spf and dkim - there's no mention of either in the headers. From or to a different server do have those headers. SPF just says which server can send those domains - but these scammers use my server to send from address 1 to address 2 (both local to my server) so even if it looked at it, it would pass

Comment: If the spammers are using your servers you are approaching the problem from the wrong side. You should fix the security of your breached servers.

Comment: Indeed, the headers make that very clear...

Comment: Please note that it is quite difficult to get suitable answers when your question does not include the relevant details.

Comment: i did say that in my question - see the title and the example i posted initially. - title says make postfix require authentication on internal emails and example explains itself